# Why does my MSBuild Exec Command Fail?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, erlang, thrift

I have a pretty simple setup for this application I'm using to test something:

> ```
>  -Solution in VS
>
>    -Project for cs code (named Client)
>
>    -Project for Thrift files( named Thrift)
>
>    -Folder for Erlang Code(Doesn't show up in VS)
> ```

The idea is I'll build the Thrift project, have it generate the code for both languages, copy the generated erlang code to the correct directory (with MSBuild, but first things first), and include the generated csharp code in the Thrift project. To do this I have the following "BeforeBuild" target:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<Exec Command="cmd /c &quot;C:\Windows\System32\thrift.exe&quot; -gen erl -gen csharp *.thrift" />
<ItemGroup>
  <CSFile Include="$(SolutionDir)gen-csharp\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I get the error "'C:\Windows\System32\thrift.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

I tried Command="thrift ..." since thrift is in my PATH, but found out that MSBuild doesn't find programs from the PATH variable.

Note: Using the command without "cmd /c" results in the same error message, but with a different error code (9001, because MSBuild is unable to find the file, instead of "cmd /c" failing to find the file).

**Edit:** For posterity, the working result is:

```
<Project>
...
(Auto generated data)
...

    <PropertyGroup>
  <CleanDependsOn>
      $(CleanDependsOn);
      CleanThriftGen;
  </CleanDependsOn>
  <ErlangProjectSrcDir>$(SolutionDir)Server\src\gen\</ErlangProjectSrcDir>
  <GenCSharpDir>gen-csharp\</GenCSharpDir>
  <GenErlDir>gen-erl\</GenErlDir>
  <ThriftDir>C:\thrift\</ThriftDir>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Exec Command="$(ThriftDir)thrift.exe -gen erl -gen csharp *.thrift" />
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ErlangSrcGroup Include="$(GenErlDir)**\*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(ErlangSrcGroup)" DestinationFiles="$(ErlangProjectSrcDir)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" ContinueOnError="false" />
</Target>
<Target Name="CleanThriftGen">
 <RemoveDir Directories="$(ErlangProjectSrcDir)" />
 <RemoveDir Directories="$(GenCSharpDir)" />
 <RemoveDir Directories="$(GenErlDir)" />
</Target>
<ItemGroup>
  <CSharpGenGroup Include="$(GenCSharpDir)**\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Is thrift.exe in same location at C:\Windows\System32\?

Comment: Yes, I tried all these commands in a command prompt and they run without error.

Comment: Also, when I move thrift.exe to the project directory and use Command="thrift.exe -gen erl -gen csharp *.thrift" or Command="thrift -gen erl -gen csharp *.thrift", it works correctly, so I know the tool is working in the context of VS, but I'm trying to use a common executable instead of copying it between all my projects. But I might just settle for copying it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the majority of my answer, in my haste I had stuck the executable in the first directory I knew would already be in my path, System32. Moving it to another folder fixes the error when running the tool directly from VS (vs cmd /c).

But I'm still not clear on what caused this. I don't know why cmd /c would be unable to find it when a command prompt with normal privileges could, and I don't know why VS couldn't find it.

As a test I gave the new folder I placed it in permissions to require administrative privileges to write to, same as System32, but VS is still able to run it from there.

Comment: You may want to use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to find out the reason.

Comment: I don't see how the Process Monitor would help